# IllegalArgumentException: Path resources/primefaces-mytheme does not start with '/'

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF / PrimeFaces project that I had deployed on a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 Server. It uses my own *theme* and until now worked without problems. However today I wanted to deploy it on a GlassFish 4.1 Server and now I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path resources/primefaces-mytheme does not start with '/'
```

There is quite a lot more:

```
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getResourcePaths(StandardContext.java:7577)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContext.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContextFacade.java:239)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResourcePaths(ExternalContextImpl.java:532)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.WebappResourceHelper.findLibrary(WebappResourceHelper.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findLibrary(ResourceManager.java:465)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getResourceInfo(ResourceManager.java:292)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:286)
(...)
```

But it's all just gibberish to me, nowhere I can see any class or file I created, so I can't put my finger on it where the error comes from. All I know is that it must be related to my theme, which is (*unpacked -> I don't use a `jar`*) under the `/resources/primefaces-mytheme` folder:

```
webapp
  +-WEB-INF
  +-resources
       +-default
       +-images
       +-primefaces-mytheme
               +-images
               +-theme.css
```

Within the `theme.css` the reference to images in the resource folder is like this:

```
url("#{resource['primefaces-mytheme:images/ui-bg_flat_0_ffffff_40x100.png']}")
```

The `css` file is actually the only place where I write out the name of my theme `primefaces-mytheme`. Where do I have to look for the reason of my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I thought it had something to do on how I use the resource folder and how I reference it, but it was actually right there before my eyes: in the deployment descriptor `web.xml` where the resources directory is declared:

**GlassFish 3.1.2.2** accepted this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**GlassFish 4** needs this: (*`/` before `resources`*)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I don't know why the earlier `GlassFish` version accepted the `param-value` without leading `/`. Maybe I had it all wrong from the beginning and GlassFish 3 kindly ignored my typo or maybe they just changed the way a directory needs to be declared.